# Having node API + Heroku deploying issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, heroku-api

[image]I have written Node API and I have uploaded in Heroku but when I want to open any other router then It shows me some error like application error. Even I got to add Procfile but there was issue Application error below I've seen "heroku logs --tail" i followed the same command but at Error and H12 i got

Can any one help me out thanks adv

Comment: do you use any framework like express for example ? and could you post the code the handle the corresponding route ?

Comment: I have used express framework 
do you want me to paste code here ? that's thousands of lines dude
even i have only one server.js file which is running main file in server and it has some req and res

Comment: for me, it's kinda hard to identify what has caused the error, you can use gist.github.com to share your code

Comment: ok wait I will share my code then

Comment: https://github.com/getinfyKiranreddy/api
here you can check my code
can you help me fast I need to do more pages dynamic .I have been doing for 3 days

Comment: If you can't post code, you should be able to find an answer to your question here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

My guess is that you forgot to res.sendfile(__dirname + 'what/ever/image.jpg')

Comment: inside `aboutus.find()` callback add this line `if (err) { console.error(err); }`, then try to access the route again, it should gives you more information about the error

Comment: what I have to do now do i need to change the error at aboutus.find() line?

Comment: @KiranReddy see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the required params on your `aboutus.find()`, which is an object. If you mean to do a find all query, you need to supply empty object on the first param, try this

```
aboutus.find({}, (err, data1) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('aboutus_edit.ejs', {
                aboutus: data1
            });
    })
```

reference: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: I guess no need to pass empty object it's already getting data from db

Comment: How do you know if the data was fetched ? Doesn't your route return no response ?

Comment: I was checking my data it is showing in table every time

Comment: after adding those lines, is there any new error message ?

Comment: I can share my screen
can you let me know what was the error if you are free

Comment: if you have anydesk or teamviewer i can connect though those